# Do browsers render gradients faster via CSS or an image?

Tags: css

I'm going to be writing a fairly graphic intensive website and the entire background of the page will contain a multi-stop linear gradient.

My question is if browsers can render it (and other animating things over it) faster if the page's background uses CSS3 to create the gradient or if it's faster to render if I create the gradient as a png and use `background-size: cover;` to create the page background.

It's draw speed I'm interested in not page load time in this instance. I *think* the png would be faster but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I had a less subjective way of measuring this, but it *seems* that using linear gradients in CSS renders better than with a large image.

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly going to be dependent on the type of gradient, the size of the gradient and what browser you are running on. It could also be impacted by layers on top of it etc.

If speed is absolutely critical then measure the two approaches side-by-side on browsers you expect most of your users to use.

Be aware that the performance could change in future releases.

Comment: I imagine pngs would give more consistent results, too. I have no evidence to back that up, mind.

Comment: Is there a way to measure render speed in a browser programmaticly?